# Eloquent - where not equal to

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm currently using the latest Laravel version.

I've tried the following queries:

```
Code::where('to_be_used_by_user_id', '<>' , 2)->get()
Code::whereNotIn('to_be_used_by_user_id', [2])->get()
Code::where('to_be_used_by_user_id', 'NOT IN', 2)->get()
```

Ideally, it should return all records except `user_id = 2`, but it returns blank array. How do I tackle this?

```
Code::all()
```

This returns all 4 records.

Code model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Code extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['value', 'registration_id', 'generated_for_user_id', 'to_be_used_by_user_id', 'code_type_id', 'is_used'];

    public function code_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CodeType');
    }

}
```

Comment: after laravel 9 added whereNot, `Code::whereNot('to_be_used_by_user_id', 2)->get()`

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Use `where` with a `!=` operator in combination with `whereNull`

```
Code::where('to_be_used_by_user_id', '!=' , 2)->orWhereNull('to_be_used_by_user_id')->get()
```

Comment: It is ignoring NULL records. If I change one of the NULLs to some non-NULL id other than 2, that record is returned. By 'it', I mean MySQL.

Answer (score 41):

For `where field not empty` this worked for me:

```
->where('table_name.field_name', '<>', '')
```

Answer (score 38):

While this seems to work

```
Code::query()
    ->where('to_be_used_by_user_id', '!=' , 2)
    ->orWhereNull('to_be_used_by_user_id')
    ->get();
```

you should not use it for big tables, because as a general rule "or" in your where clause is stopping query to use index. You are going from "Key lookup" to "full table scan"

[image] [image]

Instead, try [Union](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#unions)

```
$first = Code::whereNull('to_be_used_by_user_id');

$code = Code::where('to_be_used_by_user_id', '!=' , 2)
        ->union($first)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 13):

Or like this:

```
Code::whereNotIn('to_be_used_by_user_id', [2])->get();
```

Comment: it does not fetch null data

Answer (score 3):

Fetching data with either null and value on where conditions are very tricky. Even if you are using straight Where and OrWhereNotNull condition then for every rows you will fetch both items ignoring other where conditions if applied. For example if you have more where conditions it will mask out those and still return with either null or value items because you used orWhere condition

The best way so far I found is as follows. This works as where (whereIn Or WhereNotNull)

```
Code::where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('to_be_used_by_user_id', '!=' , 2)->orWhereNull('to_be_used_by_user_id');                  
        })->get();
```

Comment: you will have to use whereDate in case of dealing with dates

Answer (score 3):

Here's a useful scope method that you can add to your model and use it for different columns.

```
/**
 * @param Builder $query
 * @param string $field
 * @param $value
 * @return Builder
 */
public function scopeWhereNot(Builder $query, string $field, $value): Builder
{
    return $value === null
        ? $query->whereNotNull($field)
        : $query->where(function ($q) use ($field, $value) {
            return $q->where($field, '<>', $value)
                ->orWhereNull($field);
        });
}
```

and use it as follows

```
Code::whereNot('to_be_used_by_user_id', 2)->get()
```

Comment: Is'nt it `whereNot` for laravel 9?

Answer (score 1):

A number of the comments on the previous answers to this question complain that null values are not returned by the given answers.

If you want to be able to return all values that are not your condition but *include* nulls in a single line - specify using the [spaceship operator](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/null-safe-equal/) (null-safe-equals):

```
Code::whereNot('user_id','<=>',2)
```

Comment: This might be less readable than the accepted answer, however!