# Eloquent get all rows where column does NOT equal $int (!=)

Tags: php, laravel-5

Basically, I want to know how to do something like this:

```
Users::where('id' != $id)->get();
```

How do I do this with eloquent?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256933/eloquent-where-not-equal-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
Users::where('id', '!=' , $id)->get();
```

Take a look at this [Cheat Sheet](https://gist.github.com/msurguy/5654552).

Comment: If it fix your problem you can set this answer as accepted to helpe other poeple to find the solution of similar problem ;)