# Laravel Eloquent - building 'where not' query with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 5 database rows with the same `client_id`, 3 labelled `completed, Yes`.

This code pulls through 3 results as expected:

```
$indGoal = $client->indGoal()->where('completed','=','Yes')->get();
```

This code pulls through no results:  I would expect 2.

```
$indGoal = $client->indGoal()->where('completed','!=','Yes')->get();
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256933/eloquent-where-not-equal-to) suggests adding `->orWhereNull('completed')` - which works, but ignores the `client_id` relationship. The request brings through all non-`Yes` results, regardless of `$client`

My Client model for reference:

```
public function indGoal()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\IndGoal');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group `orWhere` filters in a callback so they don't interfere with existing filters.

```
$indGoal = $client->indGoal()
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->orWhere('completed', '!=', 'yes')
            ->orWhereNull('completed');
    })
    ->get();
```

This way, the query builder knows any of the grouped conditions should be true and all other conditions are independent.

Comment: This works, thanks! I don't why it works though - why is whereNull necessary in the first place?