# Laravel Where Not Equal Not Working As Expected

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've done some searcing and can't find the answer to this, so some help would be much appreciated.

I'm running the following eloquent statement:

```
        $collection= Table1::select('table1.*','table2.finish_status_id')
                                ->join('table2','table2.id','=','table1.table2_id')
                                ->where('table1.id',$id)
                                 ->where('finish_status_id','=',6)
                                ->paginate(25);
```

This query works.

However, what I actually want is this:  `->where('finish_status_id','!=',6)`
This does not work and I get no results.

These following query variations all work as expected

```
 ->where('finish_status_id','=',6)
 ->where('finish_status_id','=',null)
 ->where('finish_status_id','!=',null)
 ->where('finish_status_id','<>',null)
```

If there a reason I haven't seen as to why != is not working?

**Update:**
As per ThataL suggestion, I tried writing my query in SQL to get it to work.
I was unable to get what I originally planned, and after some digging found thi thread:
[SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Where the answer indicate NULL does not equal 'null' in SQL.  Therefore it is treated as unknown, rather than a value filled with the value of 'null'.

With my != 6 phrase, I was expecting to receive all of the null values as well.  However, on further inspection, that query works, except it also does not return null records.

After further searching I found what I was meant to be looking for on this thread: [Laravel 4 Eloquent Query Using WHERE with OR AND OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-4-eloquent-query-using-where-with-or-and-or)

Originally, simply adding a 'whereNull('finish_Status_id')' did not work, because being an or, it essentially ignore my previous where clause. (i.e., it got everything that was null, or, everything with $id).

I then updated my code to the following

```
$collection= Table1::select('table1.*','table2.finish_status_id')
                                ->join('table2','table2.id','=','table1.table2_id')
                                ->where('table1.id',$id)
                                ->where(function ($query) {
                                        $query->where('finish_status_id', '!=', 6)
                                              ->orWhereNull('finish_status_id');
                                    })
                                ->paginate(25);
```

This provide me with the solution I was after.

Comment: Can you share the sample raw query that you wanted to implement in laravel eloquent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256933/eloquent-where-not-equal-to

Comment: You should add a table name with column name `->where('table2.finish_status_id','!=',6)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code to include null into the query.

```
$collection= Table1::select('table1.*','table2.finish_status_id')
                                ->join('table2','table2.id','=','table1.table2_id')
                                ->where('table1.id',$id)
                                ->where(function ($query) {
                                        $query->where('finish_status_id', '!=', 6)
                                              ->orWhereNull('finish_status_id');
                                    })
                                ->paginate(25);
```